# python argparse named positional arguments?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

Is there a way to make python's argparse.ArgumentParser treat command line arguments the way python functions treat arguments?  So that arguments can be passed without their name?

Answer (score 8):

See the example with "integers" in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html). Don't include any hyphens and the argument will be treated as a positional argument.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('first_supplied_argument', help='help')
>>> parser.add_argument('second_supplied_argument', help='help')
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['1', '2'])
Namespace(first_supplied_argument='1', second_supplied_argument='2')
```

**Edit based on comment:**

Are you able to supply both positional and optional arguments? I think you will still need to supply at least one positional argument.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--first', help='help')
parser.add_argument('first', nargs='?', help='help')
parser.add_argument('--second', help='help')
parser.add_argument('second', nargs='?', help='help')

print parser.parse_args(['1', '2'])
print parser.parse_args(['1', '--second', '2'])
print parser.parse_args(['--first', '1', '--second', '2'])  # doesn't work
print parser.parse_args(['', '--first', '1', '--second', '2'])  # probably not what you want to do
```

Output:

```
Namespace(first='1', second='2')
Namespace(first='1', second='2')
Namespace(first=None, second=None)  # doesn't work
Namespace(first='1', second='2')
```

Comment: I want to retain the option to use the names.  I want to replicate the functionality I would get from a python function.

Comment: Are you able to supply both positional and optional arguments?

Comment: Superficially this will be similar, but not exactly the same.  You will be able to supply the values in either way.  But behavior when neither is given, or when both are used may be different.